# Taxes on Bitcoin sale in Spain

Tags: taxes, cryptocurrency, spain

I have some bitcoins that I bought back in 2012. I am now thinking about buying a house and I'd like to cash in those bitcoins to make the downpayment of the mortgage. I understand I should pay taxes for this, but I don't know how much it would be.

I found [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/81490/bringing-bitcoin-into-us-what-taxes-should-i-expect) question, but it is for the U.S., where the tax system is very different from Spain's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Trading in cryptocurrencies is considered in the same way as forex
>   trading or binary options. The same principles will apply come tax
>   time. The savings tax rates are applied (on a scale between 19% and
>   23%).
>
> As for wealth tax, cryptocurrencies have to be declared as you would
>   declare any other asset that you own.

Source:
https://jeangalea.com/bitcoin-crytpocurrencies-tax/

Comment: I just confirmed this yesterday by phone calling to spanish tax agency. The rates are 19% for the first 6,000€, 21% from 6,000.01 to 50,000 and 23% for the rest of the amount.

Comment: @mornaner So if the cryptos are treated as assets. Could you describe more precisely how are the assets taxed in Spain? Or provide some link to read more about it? Do I have to pay the tax when I perform a trade, when I convert from BTC to FIAT or when I withdraw from an exchange? Is it just the profit? Totally a newbie in this area.

Comment: @EnchanterIO According to the above statement crypto is taxed like fiat, so if you do a trade, yes, this results in a taxable event.