# How is long-term vs short-term capital gains calculated for USA resident aliens?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

Let's say I am a foreigner who bought $1,000,000 worth of Microsoft in 2010.

I have just arrived in the USA on May/01/2021 and after 6 months pass the substantial presence test and qualify as a resident alien for income tax purposes with the IRS.

If I choose to sell my $1,000,000 worth of Microsoft on Dec/01/2021 (which is now worth $2,000,000), will I have to pay the long-term capital gains rate or the short-term capital gains rate?

Comment: Looks like dupe https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48006/what-should-i-use-as-the-cost-basis-for-stock-that-was-purchased-before-becoming

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Not a duplicate. That question addresses cost basis but neglects the time factor that this question is more focused around.